# Disable row based on cell value

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, radgrid

Im trying to disable a RadGridView row based on a value in that row?
I have tried the below code in the RowLoaded event but it seems to disable all rows.

```
    var isEnrolled = (from c in masterList
                                       where c.StudentId == StudentID
                                       where c.Rolls[0].RollId == item.RollId.ToString()
                                       select c.IsEnrolled).FirstOrDefault();

            if (isEnrolled)
                e.Row.IsEnabled = false;
```

Can it be done in same event, so if a row contains the word "Confirmed" the row is disabled?

```
    foreach(DataGridRow item in RollListGrid.Items)
        {
         //Disable row if it contains "Confirmed"
        }
```

And one more, how can i check a checkbox in a row if the query returns true?

```
    var isProspectiveStudent = (from c in masterList
                                       where c.StudentId == StudentID
                                       where c.Rolls[0].RollId == item.RollId.ToString()
                                       select c.IsProspectiveStudent).FirstOrDefault();

            if (isProspectiveStudent){
                //Check the relevant checkbox
            }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted to with the below code.

```
   foreach (var x in e.Row.Cells)
        {

            if (((GridViewCell)x).Value != null && ((GridViewCell)x).Value.ToString() == "Confirmed" && x.Column.UniqueName.IndexOf("5") != -1)
            {
                e.Row.IsEnabled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```